# old apk file only run on android emulator always

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I have created one android application.

i have to run the app which means it is worked well on android emulator and device.

Afterthat  i have to change some layout height and weight(some design changes).Now i have to run these updated apk file which means the old layout design only work on android emulator...why the old apk design  is working on android emulator...i wish to work the new apk file on android emulator...

how can i resolve these error ??? please help me ...

Comment: posting logcat output of the crash won't hurt your health, trust me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:-

1. Make sure there is no error in any of the `XML` in the project.
2. Clean & Build your project again.
3. Run the application on your emulator(new apk will be now generated in the bin folder).

If the above don't work, try to clear the user data when starting a new emulator instance, try running your updated application then.

Comment: I doubt if the changes are getting reflected in the new apk. Anyways, post the logcat for the crash.

Comment: i got the o/p .i have mistake in my code.yes i have created layout,layout-large ,layout-small folders.here some file is missed in that large and medium folder.thats y i didn't get the o/p.now its perfectly worked.

Answer (score 2):

i have done a simple thing that solve my problem whenever i get this kind of chaos !
1. Open Your emulator
2. Goto Setting>manage app or apps(ver 4.1)>your app
3. now uninstall your app from the emulator.
4. clean your project and then make your changes
5. run the fresh app again
6. BOOOM your app is now running 
if you still got problems then discuss it in comments :)